# how to handle it easily when failed to ssh gce due to fstab invalid configuration

Tags: ssh, centos, google-compute-engine

On GCE, I added a disk to my VM and changed the `fstab` file to mount disk automatically. But I made a mistake in that file so I couldn't ssh this vm any more.
In my opinion, I need to edit that file correctly then I can ssh it again. The problem is I couldn't login first to edit it.
Are there some ways to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [interactive serial console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console) to revert the changes you might have done.
[Refer to this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/gce-discussion/FzTzy_ML_D8/ZOsCau39AAAJ).

- create a root password for the serial console
- login into the instance and revert the changes